# How can search google using urllib3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-search, urllib3

Im trying to retrieve a list of urls from a google search, here is my current implementation using urllib:

the query is searching last fm for two specific tags

```
def searchTags(tag1, tag2):
    query = input( 'site:last.fm/music intitle:"tags for" "'+ tag1 + '" "'+ tag2 +'"' )
    query = urllib.urlencode( { 'q' : query } )
    response = urllib.urlopen( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
    json = m_json.loads( response )
    results = json[ 'responseData' ][ 'results' ]
    print(results)
    for result in results:
        title = result['title']
        url = result['url']   # was URL in the original and that threw a name error exception
        print( title + '; ' + url )
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you are facing?

Comment: First retrieve the html after querying to Google then extract links using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)